# How to use fscrawler in ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, elasticsearch, fscrawler

Is it possible to use fscrawler in ubuntu? I have used on windows and it works fine. When I try to follow the same implementation on ubuntu I am getting all kind of errors.

First I just tried to pull the docker image and run it according to this guide https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation and getting the image with `docker pull dadoonet/fscrawler`

When I tried to run it with  `docker run -it --rm -v /home/index:/root/.fscrawler -v /home/messages:/tmp/es:ro dadoonet/fscrawler fscrawler job_name` I got this error

```
/usr/bin/fscrawler: 47: /usr/bin/fscrawler: ps: not found
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '4e0e2f2a' at 'null' in 'null'
```

After that I tried to fllow this tutorial [fscrawler tutorial](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/tutorial.html) to install it and use it in linux. Idownloaded the fscrawler-es7-2.8-SNAPSHOT version, but running `bin/fscrawler resumes` in the folder where I unzipped the files just gave me this error `bin/fscrawler: command not found`

Is there any way to use fscrawler in a linux system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug on Docker. (https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/issues/1229)

If you install it manually (install the JVM and FSCrawler) it should work well.